# Keystone "node web" Error module.js:327

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystone

I'm trying to build a website with keystone and got an error at the last point of the getting started documentation.

> "Now you're ready to run your application, so execute the following in your project's main folder: node web"

When I'm in my terminal on MacOS I typed in:

`node web /Users/Nici/Documents/Jens/Website`

And then the Terminal throws out the following code:

```
    node web /Users/Nici/Documents/Jens/Website 
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Nici/web'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

I installed the `node.js-pkg` in the standard location.

In the Documentation it says that I have to create new project files to a location where I want to.

Comment: the code that is throwing the error? (nearby line `327`)

Comment: thanks for your Idea, I updated the Error.
Where i can find the module.js file?

Comment: I meant to add the actual source code, not the full error stacktrace :)

Comment: I misunderstood the stacktrace, I think this error is due to the fact that it's not finding a module called "web" under the `/Users/Nici/web` directory... have you inited a proper package? what is the entry point set in your `package.json` ? what are the files in that folder?

Comment: First, I've to say that my directory to my website folder is another than /Users/Nici/web. There isn't a "web" file. The files are in /Users/Nici/Documents/Jens/Website . I can't find a proper package. :/

Comment: then you're using the command `node` the wrong way. Take a look at the man page, you should pass it a script to execute. Hence you should get yourself inside the directory where there's the script that starts your application and there run `node the-file.js`.

I'd suggest you to create in that directory a proper node package via `npm init` and define in the generated `package.json` your start script

Comment: Okay thanks for that for now, I should try this later. I think I misunderstood it to use the node command in the terminal of OSX.

Comment: I think it could be that.. let me know the result :)

Comment: Hey, I saw that I've got a package.json file.
In it is this code:
`{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "keystone": "latest",
    "underscore": "latest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.3.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "web.js"
  }
}`

How can I run this file and where do I have to input the `node web` comment?
Sorry for my newbie questions. :D

Comment: Try running `npm run start`

Comment: Everytime I get this Error: `npm ERR! path /Users/Nici/package.json`
My Path is completly different, like you know already. :/

Comment: Are you running it from the directory where the `package.json` file is? :)

Comment: I typed in: `npm run start /Users/Nici/Documents/Jens/Website`
In the "Website" Folder is the package.json file and the web.js file. But I get this Error:
`npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start" "/Users/Nici/Documents/Jens/Website"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! path /Users/Nici/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Nici/package.json'`

Comment: The answer was, that I had to go into the folder with the terminal using: 'cd "Path"'. But then there were another errors, so I decided to install it new in another folder. There I got these Errors and I think I'm going forward to the result :D >my-site@0.0.0 "Path" >none >sh: none: command not found.              In the package.json file at the end there is the code : "script": "none"

Comment: Great to know you have proceeded! If you're having other errors not related to this question I'd suggest you to ask a new question :) Otherwise edit this one with the new informations :)

Comment: Another update for you :) my localhost website runs! A MongoDB error occurred because I hadn't the rights for it. I could only read. I'm happy now and thanks for your help! :D